# What is notion of diagram and cone from category theory to topological space

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

I  was reading Steve Awodey's book Category Theory and [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9951/limits-in-category-theory-and-analysis).

In the book *Category Theory*, the author Steve Awodey introduced diagram on the page $101:$

> Let $\textbf{J}$ and $\textbf{C}$ be categories. A diagram of type $\textbf{J}$ in $\textbf{C}$ is a functor.
>   $$D:\textbf{J} \to \textbf{C}.$$
>   We write the objects in the "index category" $\textbf{J}$ lower case, $i,j,...$ and the values of the functor $D: \textbf{J} \to \textbf{C}$ in the form $D_i,D_j,$ etc.
>
> A cone to a diagram $D$ consists of an object $C$ in $\textbf{C}$ and a family of arrows in $\text{C},$
>   $$c_j:C \to D_j$$
>   one for each object $j \in J,$ such that for each arrow $\alpha:i \to j$ in $\textbf{J},$ the following triangle commutes:
>   \begin{array}{ccc}  &C & \\ \swarrow^{c_i}&&\searrow^{c_j}\\
>  D(i)&\rightarrow^{D_{\alpha}}&D(j) \end{array}

I really have no idea of designing commutative diagram in latex. But the key thing is whether there is a notion of diagram and cone in topological space. I am curious because in the later section, Awodey discussed the continuity of functors. And I am interested in the diagram and cone because I think there might be some kind of concept about them in topological space.

Comment: I don't understand.  Let $\mathbf{C}$ be the category of topological spaces and apply the definitions

Comment: @Randall Then what are the diagrams then?

Comment: Spaces and continuous maps?  Are you asking if there is a notion of cone in spaces that existed "before" the categorical definition?

Comment: @Randall Yes, that is exactly what I am asking for.

Comment: Try this:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_limit

Comment: Also, continuity of functors will just mean preservation of limits.  It won't abstract continuity from topology.

Comment: For diagrams in MathJax, you can use AMScd, as explained [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/16888#16888). But it doesn't allow diagonals, so I guess your construction is as good as possible.